# Отрисовать фиругу. чтобы псевдоэлемент принимал её форму

Tags: html, css

```css
.dropdawn-block__number {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
  padding: 6px 13px 13px 11px;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0, 100% 0, 100% 70%, 0 100%);
  font-family: "Orchidea Pro";
  font-size: 50px;
  color: rgb(253, 167, 0);
  background: rgb(13, 43, 109);
}
.dropdawn-block__number::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0, 100% 0, 100% 70%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<span class="dropdawn-block__number">1</span>
```

[image: должно получиться вод так]

```css
 .dropdawn-block__number {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0, 100% 0, 100% 73%, 0 100%);
  font-family: "Orchidea Pro";
  font-size: 50px;
  color: rgb(253, 167, 0);
  background: rgb(13, 43, 109);
}
.dropdawn-block__number::before,.dropdawn-block__number ::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  clip-path: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.dropdawn-block__number::before {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50.7%) scale(91%, 92%);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
 .dropdawn-block__number::after {
  content: attr(data-num);
  transform: translate(-9%, -9%) scale(87.5%, 89%);
}
```

```html
                <span class="dropdawn-block__number" data-num="1"></span>
```

Comment: Помогите решить проблему. Не получается отрисовать как нужно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте более подробное описание вашей проблемы в ваш вопрос, для этого нажмите [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1506060/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простейшая задача. Даже не пойму, где может возникнуть затруднение.

```css
/* For example only --> */ body{margin:0;min-height:100vh;background-color:#fff;background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png'),radial-gradient(#fff8,#000f);display:flex;justify-content:space-around;align-items:center;background-position:0 0;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:auto}

.dropdawn-block__number {
  font: bold 65vh/1.1em "Orchidea Pro", sans-serif; /* Size original - 320px */
  position: relative;
  width: 1em; height: 1.4375em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fda700;
  background-color: #0d2b6d;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0, 100% 0, 100% 73%, 0 100%);
}
.dropdawn-block__number::before,
.dropdawn-block__number::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  width: inherit; height: inherit;
  clip-path: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.dropdawn-block__number::before {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50.7%) scale(91%, 92%);
  background-color: #8695b6;
}
.dropdawn-block__number::after {
  content: attr(data-num);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50.9%) scale(87.5%, 89%);
}
```

```html
<span class="dropdawn-block__number" data-num="2"></span>
```

Варианты. Всё настраивается в родительском элементе (для наглядности вынес настройки в inline-стили):

```css
/* For example only --> */ body{margin:0;min-height:100vh;background-color:#fff;background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png'),radial-gradient(#fff8,#000f);display:flex;justify-content:space-around;align-items:center;background-position:0 0;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:auto}

.dropdawn-block__number {
  font-size: 320px; /* Масштаб элемента */
  font-family: 'Orchidea Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  position: relative;
  width: 1em; height: 1.4375em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fda700; /* Цвет шрифта */
  background-color: #0d2b6d; /* Цвет заливки */
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0, 100% 0, 100% 73%, 0 100%);
}
.dropdawn-block__number::before,
.dropdawn-block__number::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  width: inherit; height: inherit;
  clip-path: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.dropdawn-block__number::before {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50.7%) scale(91%, 92%);
  background-color: #8695b6;
}
.dropdawn-block__number::after {
  content: attr(data-num);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50.9%) scale(87.5%, 89%);
}
```

```html
<span style="font-size: 24px; color: #fff; background-color: #000;" class="dropdawn-block__number" data-num="1"></span>
<span style="font-size: 44px; color: #fa0; background-color: #0d2b6d;" class="dropdawn-block__number" data-num="2"></span>
<span style="font-size: 64px; color: #0ff; background-color: #080;" class="dropdawn-block__number" data-num="3"></span>
<span style="font-size: 84px; color: #00f; background-color: #f00;" class="dropdawn-block__number" data-num="4"></span>
```

Comment: спасибо за решение. не пойму почему, взял стили, но коректно не отображает.

Comment: @user483434: если здесь всё работает, то ищите ошибку у себя. Возможно какие-то другие стили влияют.

Comment: мне там нужен absolut, но всё равно дело не в нём.

Comment: @user483434: нужен absolut ? Не вижу препятствий.

Comment: супер. теперь осталось разобраться, что я делаю не так) я посмотрел все стили и у меня в целом нет тог, чтобы могло перебивать их.

Comment: Я второй раз размещаю правки, а он почему-то не выставляет их. Может сейчас будет видно результат

Comment: @user483434: так зачем Вы мой ответ пытаетесь править? Правьте вопрос, добавляйте подробности туда.

Comment: Понял. Внес изменения. Посмотри пожалуйста.

Comment: @user483434: посмотрел. Я делал один в один, как на картинке, а Вы изменили не разобравшись. Размер элемента зависит от размера шрифта, больше менять ничего не требуется.

Comment: не много не понял. размер то меняется и размер я могу контролировать (блока и цифры), во только не пойму как контролировать заливку.

Comment: @user483434: на картинке то, что Вам нужно? Или это "левая" картинка?

Comment: нет, всё верно. как на картинке и так как у вас получилось.

Comment: @user483434: В моём коде нет лишних строчек. Что конкретно Вы хотите изменить? Цвет?

Comment: нет. я прикрепил свой вариант выше. а мне нужно как у вас. я взял все стили, но у меня не получаются полоски белые. у меня получилась заливка полностью блока.

Comment: @user483434: добавил вариант. Внимательно разберитесь что и за что отвечает.

Comment: я не понимаю, что не так. просто как у вас переношу все стили, и у меня та же херня отображается. у вас по всему блоку полоски ( как и нужно), а у меня полная заливка ( херня).(

Comment: пиздец. я решил проблему! Спасибо вам большое! За терпение)

Comment: Мне здесь нужно что-то нажимать, за вашу помощь?)

Comment: @user483434: у меня `translate(-50%, -50.9%) scale(87.5%, 89%)` , а у Вас `translate(-9%, -9%) scale(87.5%, 89%)` . Здесь точно нет разницы? И зачем вы меняете ширину и высоту - сказано же, что масштаб зависит от font-size.

Comment: @user483434: лучшая благодарность здесь - это галочка рядом с голосованием за ответ. Ну и если помогло, то я уже рад.